# How to rearrange/arrange the divs in css?

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to do a page like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qwht1q96idtc22/hf.png?dl=0 with this parameters :

```
Background: red
header: 70px tall, black background, is always at the top of your browser       (fixed position), total width
Content: 500px wide, centered in height matches the contents of a blue background, the browser scrolljának top position 30px from the header
Left column: 300px wide (including frame), 550px high and 25px from the container to containing a yellow background, black border 5px
Right column: 125px wide, 200px high, white background, 25px on the container to contain'
```

I just did this : https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=hazikep.jpg

With this code :

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


html, body
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

#fejlec{
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
background-position:top;
background-attachment:fixed;
position: fixed;
}

#kek{

background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top:170px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}

#sarga{
background-color: yellow;
width:260px;
height: 550px;
padding:20px;
border:5px solid black;
position: absolute;
top:-25px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
float: left ;


}

#feher
{
background-color: white;
width:125px;
height: 200px;
padding:25px;
}
```

I don't know who to do arrange divs with css, so it could be very useful, if somebody could help me.

Comment: We have to sign in for your second dropbox link. Please revise. Also, where is the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/hex8xsbs/

html:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div><div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html {
  background: red;
}

.header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}   

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: yellow;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 125px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra closing `div`. Otherwise nice solution.

Comment: Good call – fixed.

Answer (score -1):

there are many ways of achieving that layout.

another (similar) solution to switz's one could be:

the HTML

```
<div id="fejlec"></div>
<div id="kek">
  <div id="sarga"></div>
  <div id="feher"></div>
  <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


html, body
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#fejlec {
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
top: 0
}

#kek {
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
margin: 100px auto 0;
padding: 20px;
}

#sarga {
background-color: yellow;
width:260px;
height: 550px;
padding:20px;
float: left;
border:5px solid black;
}

#feher {
background-color: white;
width:26%;
height: 200px;
padding:25px;
float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/njb9aj5z/